Please explain the difference between HFC technology and PEMFC technology
I understand how hydrogen fuel cells (HFCs) function, but what are the differences between them and PEMFC's?
I know that there are HT-PEMFCs and LT-PEMFCs, for low and high temperatures.
Do PEMFCs involve heat consumption to generate electricity in some way as compared to HFC's which just take in H2 and O2?

PEMFC are a subset of HFC. Many HFC's run at high temperatures; PEMFC's are designed to run at lower temps.
Many generic fuel cells and PEMFC's have to be heated to operating temperature, not to provide input energy, but for the action to proceed at a reasonable rate. Consider a candle: the match provides little energy, but raises the waxed wick to ignition temperature.

Ok, so PEMFC's have few differences from mainline HFC's, just that they are able to operate at lower temperatures?
